# In Beaker notebook, If something crashes or I get disconnected, can I recover my work?

Tags: beaker-notebook

Does Beaker automatically save my work? What will happen if I get disconnected in the middle of a project?

Comment: Please note that self-answered questions must meet the same quality standards as any others, and thus far your efforts in [tag:beaker-notebook] do not appear to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Beaker saves your notebooks as you edit them automatically every 60 seconds. Look in **~/.beaker/v1/var/sessionBackups** to find your work.

Also, if the client becomes disconnected from the server, it tries for 5 seconds to reconnect, but if it cannot, Beaker gives you a chance to save a copy of your notebook locally.